# Simple javascript if statement with charAt is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its simple, if a user enters a number that does not beggin with 6 or 9, he gets error:

```
console.log($(this).val().charAt(0));

if($(this).val().charAt(0) != 6 || $(this).val().charAt(0) != 9){
     x=false;
  }else {
     x=true;
  }
```

Console.log correctly displays the first character.. that means the value exists..

But no matter if I type 6 or 7 or 9, i will always get false... Why?

Comment: Think one second about the OR here.

Comment: Well: `||` = `OR` :)

Comment: what will happen when it is 6, you have `6 != 6 || 6 != 9`, so the second expression is truthy, same of 9(then the first expression becomes truthy), so your condition will always return true

Comment: You should try regex `/^[69]/`

Comment: || = OR , Your condition is not valid

Comment: @Rajesh Either `/^[69]/` or `/^(6|9)/` but not `/^[6|9]/`

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yes. Just updated it. Thanks! [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkug0L6w/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert the logic conditions as both states cannot possibly be true at the same time, so `x` is always set to `false`. Try this:

```
var chr = $(this).val().charAt(0);
if (chr == '6' || chr == '9') {
    x = true;
} else {
    x = false;
}
```

From there you can now see that you don't even need the `if` condition as you can set `x` directly, like this:

```
var chr = $(this).val().charAt(0);
var x = chr == '6' || chr == '9';
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the value of `somevar`,

```
somevar!=6 OR somevar!=9
```

is always true.

The best solution here would probably be a regular expression:

```
var x = /^[69]/.test($(this).val());
```